# JQuery click edit post and selected id does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a post edit. But i have some problem.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QNKwWo)** from codepen.io.

In this demo you can see there are two edit `(red)` button. When you click the first edit button then the text and image edit area will be come on there. But if you check the developer console you can see the image id is not real image ids. Like the normaly first image `id="1"` and second image `id="2"` but after click edit button, edit area image ids is not for second image `id="2"` all image `id="1"` what is the problem in my jquery code.

Also how can i put image id from `<div class="del" id="here">x</div>`

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
      <div class="postInfo">
         <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Home-Sweet-Home-Wallpaper.jpg" class="ab" id="1">
       </div>
       <div class="postInfo">
         <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Home-Sweet-Home-Wallpaper.jpg" class="ab" id="2">
       </div>
      <div class="ptx"> fdasfads fsasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsas</div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="1">Edit1</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
      <div class="postInfo">
         <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" class="ab" id="2">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf aldsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsassssg5
      </div>
      <div class="ptx"> fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsas</div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="2">Edit2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var selected = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo img").parent().html();
      var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html();
      var imid = $(".postInfo img").attr("id");
      var editImage = $('<div class="edi"><div class="del" id="imageid">x</div>' + selected + '</div>').html();
      var editMarkUp = '<div class="edBtnS"><div class="edSv">Save</div><div class="cNeD" id="' + ID + '">Cancel</div></div><textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea>';
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html(editMarkUp);
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editImage);
      var data = $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val();
      $('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus();
      $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(data + ' ');
   });
   $("body").on("click", ".cNeD", function(event) {
      $(".editBtn").prop('disabled', false);
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var currentMessageText = $("#txtmessage_" + ID).html();
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html(currentMessageText);
   });
});
```

Comment: First of all you can't use same id value multiple times; id="2"

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yes i know dear. I want to learn how can i do that. I need help here.

Comment: This is because of selector you are using returning first element id i.e. 1

Comment: Put something like img11, img12, etc for 1st set and img21, etc for 2nd set

Comment: try the answer below added. You have to set scope for image...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var selected = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo img").parent().html();
      var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html();
      $(".postInfo", $("#messageB" + ID)).each(function() {
        $('.edi .del', $(this)).show();
     });

     var editMarkUp = '<div class="edBtnS"><div class="edSv">Save</div><div class="cNeD" id="' + ID + '">Cancel</div></div><textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea>';

    $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html(editMarkUp);
    var data = $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val();
    $('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus();
    $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(data + ' ');
 });
 $("body").on("click", ".cNeD", function(event) {
   $(".editBtn").prop('disabled', false);
   var ID = $(this).attr("id");
   var currentMessageText = $("#txtmessage_" + ID).html();

   $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html(currentMessageText);
  
   $(".postInfo", $("#messageB" + ID)).each(function() {
      $('.edi .del', $(this)).hide();
   });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
   margin:0px auto;
   width:100%;
   max-width:550px;
   background-color:#d8dbdf;
   border-radius:2px;
   margin-top:50px;
   padding:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.postAr {
   padding:20px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#f5f5f5;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
}
.cNeD {
   background-color:blue;
   color:#ffffff;
   padding:5px;
   width:100px;
}
.postInfo {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   float:left;
}
.editBtn {
   width:50px;
   padding:10px;
   background-color:red;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
   color:#ffffff;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.del {
   position:absolute;
  right:0px;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   background-color:red;
   border-radius:50%;
   -webkit-border-radius:50%;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:20px;
   color:#ffffff;
   font-weight:bold;
   z-index:1;
}
.postInfo img {
   width:100%;
}
.ptx {
   width:100%;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
.edi {
   position:relative;
}
.edi img {
   border-radius:2px;
   width:100%;
}
/* hide delete button  by default */

.edi .del {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
    <div class="postInfo">
      <div class="edi">
        <div class="del" id="1">x</div>
        <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Home-Sweet-Home-Wallpaper.jpg" class="ab" id="1">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="postInfo">
     <div class="edi">
        <div class="del" id="2">x</div>
        <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Home-Sweet-Home-Wallpaper.jpg" class="ab" id="2">
     </div>
  </div>
    <div class="ptx"> fdasfads fsasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsas</div>
    <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="1">Edit1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
   <div class="postInfo">
     <div class="edi">
        <div class="del" id="2">x</div>
        <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" class="ab" id="2">
     </div>
     fdasfads fasd fadsf aldsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsassssg5
  </div>
  <div class="ptx"> fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsas</div>
  <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="2">Edit2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the different here ?

Comment: You are using var imid = $(".postInfo img").attr("id"); I have added scope $("#messageB" + ID) to this var imid = $(".postInfo img", $("#messageB" + ID)).attr("id");

Comment: @itzmukesy7 there are same id why i need to do that ? I want to add real image id. If i use your answer the images ids already 1 not 1 and 2.

Comment: But you are not using it anywhere imig then why you want to work on this img id?

Comment: when i click edit1 for first post then you know can see the image ids is different first image id 1 and second image id 2 . I want to put that image ids on the editable area. So for now my jquery code putting id just 1. Check it before clicked and after clicked image ids.

Comment: Where img id is added?

Comment: need to add img id from here `<div class="del" id="'HERE'">x</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106204/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-devstud).